# Creating a get/set function (like jQuery) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate the jQuery style getter/setters in this script. I know I could take the `_text` variable from inside the `responseText` function and make this work, but I don't understand why what I currently have doesn't work.

Is it possible to keep the `_text` variable private to the `responseText` function and have this function work like I wish it?

I've got a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brxaetty/

code:

```
var responseText = function(text) {
    var _text = 'goodbye world';
    var _responseText = function(response) {
        if (response) {
            _text = response;
        } else {
            return _text;
        }

    };
    if (text) {
        _responseText(text);
    } else {
        return _responseText(text);
    }
}
console.log(responseText()); //should be goodbye world
responseText('hello world'); //should set _text to hello world
console.log(responseText()); //should say hello world, does not
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var responseText = function(text) {
    var _text = 'goodbye world';
    return function(response) {
        if (response) {
            _text = response;
        } else {
            return _text;
        }

    };
}();
console.log(responseText()); //should be goodbye world
responseText('hello world'); //should set _text to hello world
console.log(responseText()); //says hello world
```

What i've done here is create a closure, keep `_text` inside that closure, and then return a function. This function is inside the closure, and has a reference to `_text`, and is able to work properly.

(To see console output from the snippet, see my MSE feature request and userscript: [Add a console to Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/259693))

In your original code, you were recreating `_text` each time, so it was never saved across invocations.

Comment: can you explain why what I have did not work?  it seemed reasonable enough to me that it would.  was the private _responseText not closure-y enough?

Comment: Yeah, i added something to the end of the answer.

Comment: i still don't understand why your solution does not suffer the same shortfall as mine.  can you clarify? thanks.

Comment: My solution uses an IIFE, and returns a function. This new, inner function, is able to work as intended, because it's in the closure. Your solution just returned a single value. Additionally, every time you invoked the function, `_text` would be redefined, and so could never be set.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense :).  i don't know that i would have had an elegant of a solution.  one last thing, was it possible to get the script to perform in the manner that i had it (or something close)? +1, thanks

Comment: This is actually pretty close to your original code, and also the most efficient way of doing it (that i know of).